# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val' in Python Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list

I have recently started to practice using LinkedList in Python and encountered the problem below. Both code seems like they are doing the same thing but 1 got the error while the other did not. Can someone let me know why this is the case?:

The `ListNode` class is defined as:

```
#Python Linked List
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

Assume we have this linked list:

```
node = ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}
```

#### Code 1

This can run fine and will print "2 4 3":

```
while node:
    print(node.val) # access the values of the node by node.val
    node=node.next`
```

#### Code 2:

This gives me an error saying 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val' while still printing "2"

```
node = node.next
print(node.val)
```

I expect to see code 2 to print "2" and *not* giving me the error.

Note that code 1 and code 2 are run independently with

```
node = ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}
```

In fact, code 2 **does print 2**, it just prints 2 with the `Nonetype` error, which I want to avoid.

Comment: It's because you have set default value for the property "next" as None.

Comment: It's not clear if these are actually running one after the other, or if you're usually running them independently but just pasted them next to each other for the question.

Comment: What specifically is the "correct value" that you expect code 2 to print?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Assuming that node has already been defined, I have added some lines defining a value for node.

Comment: Again: what do you expect code 2 to print?  Do you think it should print `2` (the value `node` had before code 1 modified it) or `3` (the last value code 1 printed before it exhausted the list)?

Comment: I expect it to print 2. Code 1 and code 2 are run independently with node = ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}. In fact, code 2 does print 2, it just print 2 with the Nonetype error.

Comment: *"In fact, code 2 does print 2, it just print 2 with the Nonetype error."*: I cannot reproduce that. Please review, and provide the *exact* code, including for the initialisation of the list, so that we can just copy your code and run it and see the output and error you speak of.

Comment: I edited your question to incorporate the additional information you have provided in comments. Please check that it is OK, but then add more information, as the `NoneType` error does not occur when running this code with the given linked list. I suspect you have something wrong in the **creation** of that linked list, so please add that initialisation code to your question.

Comment: I replicated this on LeetCode playground! What caused me frustration is it prints the objects properly if I check the `node` is None or not before doing `print(node.val)`, but I got `NoneType object has no attribute val` if I don't check, which is quite weird. I am pretty sure the `node` I am invoking is not None.

Answer (score 1):

After your while loop finished you are at the last `node` in your linked list.
So `node.next` will point to `None` as per your definition:

```py
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you have set the default values for the properties "val" as 0, "next" as None. If supposed that you have created an instance, None will be assigned to the "next" property of the instance. If you want to access to the "next" property, create another instance and assign it to the "next" property of the previous instance

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
   
node1 = ListNode()
node2 = ListNode()

node1.next = node2
print(node1.next)
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to access the val attribute or traverse the next pointer of a None object would result in an AttributeError and cause the code to fail. Checking for None helps to ensure that the function handles all possible cases.

```
        if node:
            print(node.val)
```